# Can't get cout to display decimals c++

Tags: c++

i can't get `cout` to display decimals (using eclipse c++ and mingw)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 55, b = 60, c = 70;

    double avgResult;

    avgResult = ((a + b + c) / 3);

    cout << avgResult;  //should display 61.666666

    return 0;
}
```

my output is 61 when I would expect it to be 61.666666.

I can get it to display the decimals using

`cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << avrResult;`

but I thought I didn't need to do that unless I wanted a specific decimal precision.

If I do something like

```
double value = 12.345;
cout << value;
```

it displays correctly so it leads me to believe that the above problem has to do with the use of `int` values in my calculation of `double avgResult`

btw I am new to c++ and am just starting to learn

Comment: Ah, an issue with integer math versus double math. We all did this exact same thing at one point!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`((a + b + c) / 3)` - that has an `int` type. Change it to `((a + b + c) / 3.0)` to get `double`

Answer (score 1):

You compute (a + b + c) / 3 and then you store it in avgResult.
avgResult is a double, but a + b + c is int, 3 is int, so the result of division is int. So you finally store an int in your double variable.

Another way to get a double result, besides the already mentioned one:

```
avgResult = a + b + c;
avgResult /= 3;
```